# I have a problem with a function, it does not return anything and when I call it and when I try to call it tells me that I have not defined variable

Tags: python, function, undefined

```
try:
    print("This program will allow you to calculate the average of your califications \nonly accepts 4 grades")
    
    opc=int(input("type (1) to calculate a simple average or type (2) \nto calculate the weighted average: "))
    n1 =int(input("Write your first calification: "))
    n2 = int(input("Write your second calification: "))
    n3= int(input("Write your third calification: "))
    n4= int(input("Write your fourth calification: "))
    def promedio(opc,prom):
        if opc == 1:# simple average calification
            p= (n1+n2+n3+n4)/4
            print("your average calification is : ",p)
             
        elif opc == 2:# weight average calification
            p1=int(input("insert the weighted of your first calification: "))
            p2=int(input("insert the weighted of your second calification: "))
            p3=int(input("insert the weighted of your third calification: "))
            p4=int(input("insert the weighted of your fourth calification: "))
            p=p1*n1+p2*n2+p3*n3+p4*n4
            print("your weighted average calification is: ",p)
            
        else:
            print("your average calification is")
        return prom
    x = promedio(p)
    print(x)

    
    
except:
    print("write only a number 1 or 2")
```

Comment: I hope you know ```x = promedio(p)``` you are passing one argument but the function needs 2

Comment: you have not assigned any value to this variable p.you are passing it in the argument

Comment: ```p``` is defined inside the function. This will lead to an error

Answer (score 0):

```
            opc=int(input("type (1) to calculate a simple average or type (2) \nto calculate the weighted average: "))
            n1 =int(input("Write your first calification: "))
            n2 = int(input("Write your second calification: "))
            n3= int(input("Write your third calification: "))
            n4= int(input("Write your fourth calification: "))
            def promedio(opc,arr):
                if opc == 1:# simple average calification
                     p= (arr[0]+arr[1]+arr[2]+arr[3])/4
                     print("your average calification is : ",p)
     
                elif opc == 2:# weight average calification
                     p1=int(input("insert the weighted of your first calification: "))
                     p2=int(input("insert the weighted of your second calification: "))
                     p3=int(input("insert the weighted of your third calification: "))
                     p4=int(input("insert the weighted of your fourth calification: "))
                     p=p1*arr[0]+p2*arr[1]+p3*arr[2]+p4*arr[3]
                     print("your weighted average calification is: ",p)
    
                else:
                     print("your average calification is")
                return p
           arr=[n1,n2,n3,n4]
           x = promedio(opc,arr)
           print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the suggestions by @Sujay, the function argument you need in `promedio` should modify, and return value should be `p`.

```
try:
    print("This program will allow you to calculate the average of your califications \nonly accepts 4 grades")
    
    opc=int(input("type (1) to calculate a simple average or type (2) \nto calculate the weighted average: "))
    n1 =int(input("Write your first calification: "))
    n2 = int(input("Write your second calification: "))
    n3= int(input("Write your third calification: "))
    n4= int(input("Write your fourth calification: "))
    def promedio(opc):
        if opc == 1:# simple average calification
            p= (n1+n2+n3+n4)/4
            print("your average calification is : ",p)
             
        elif opc == 2:# weight average calification
            p1=int(input("insert the weighted of your first calification: "))
            p2=int(input("insert the weighted of your second calification: "))
            p3=int(input("insert the weighted of your third calification: "))
            p4=int(input("insert the weighted of your fourth calification: "))
            p=p1*n1+p2*n2+p3*n3+p4*n4
            print("your weighted average calification is: ",p)
            
        else:
            print("your average calification is")
        return p
    x = promedio(opc)
    print(x)
except:
    print("write only a number 1 or 2")
```